# How to count two rows with the same DATE and TIME as 1 row

Tags: sql, date, count, sum

```
ID       |         Date      |    Status      |      Physician ID

44397479   10/13/2009 17:40     NOSHOW
44397480   10/13/2009 16:40     CHECKED OUT            108 
44397481   10/13/2009 14:32     CHECKED OUT            108
44397482   10/14/2009 10:44     RESCHEDULED            108
44397483    8/26/2009 12:35     RESCHEDULED            108
44397484   10/13/2009 15:26     CHECKED OUT            108
56084463   10/10/2009 10:00     PENDING                108
56287658   10/14/2009 10:44     PENDING                108
54728032   10/13/2009 15:56     CHECKED OUT            108
```

This is a sample from a table that contains millions of records.

I need to write a query that will count any two rows that meet the following criteria:

1. The 2 rows have the same time (only time, not date)
2. The status of one row is `RESCHEDULED` and the other row is `PENDING`

I want to display the two rows, as one row only(in the `SUM` function) for each Physician.

How can I achieve this with SQL?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: What are you summing - and what are you supposed to do with the rows that don't meet the criteria?

Answer (score 0):

This should help you in the right direction. *(Full example)*. Now you should be able to group by what you require, and sum the *Dups* field.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID INT,
        [Date] DATETIME,
        [Status] VARCHAR(100),
        [Physician ID] INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 44397479,'10/13/2009 17:40','NOSHOW' , NULL
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 44397480,'10/13/2009 16:40','CHECKED OUT' ,108  
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 44397481,'10/13/2009 14:32','CHECKED OUT' ,108 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 44397482,'10/14/2009 10:44','RESCHEDULED' ,108 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 44397483,'8/26/2009 12:35','RESCHEDULED' ,108 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 44397484,'10/13/2009 15:26','CHECKED OUT' ,108 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 56084463,'10/10/2009 10:00','PENDING' ,108 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 56287658,'10/14/2009 10:44','PENDING' ,108 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 54728032,'10/13/2009 15:56','CHECKED OUT' ,108 


SELECT  *,
        CASE 
            WHEN    t.[Status] = 'PENDING' 
                AND EXISTS(
                        SELECT  * 
                        FROM    @Table 
                        WHERE   DATEPART(hh, [Date]) = DATEPART(hh, t.[Date]) 
                        AND     DATEPART(MI, [Date]) = DATEPART(MI, t.[Date]) 
                        AND     ID <> t.ID) 
                        AND     [Physician ID] = t.[Physician ID]
                        AND     Status = 'RESCHEDULED'
                THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
        END Dups
FROM    @Table t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.[Physician ID], count(*) as Count
from @Table t1
inner join @Table t2 on (
    t1.date - cast(t1.date as int) = t2.date - cast(t2.date as int)
    and t1.Status = 'RESCHEDULED' and t2.Status = 'PENDING'
    and t1.[Physician ID] = t2.[Physician ID]
)
group by t1.[Physician ID]
```